# Should you always put join() after launching a thread?

Tags: c++, multithreading

I wonder if there is any advantage putting `join()` not immediately after launching a thread?

```cpp
std::thread t(func);

// some code ...

t.join();
```

does it give you any advantage or it's always preferable to use it after a thread launch?

```cpp
std::thread t(func);
t.join();

// some code ...
```

Comment: `join` should be put at the points which are important for synchronization. Putting it right after thread launch is defeating the whole point of parallelization. That is, you are making the main thread to block until the whole other thread is finished instead of doing something useful in the same time.

Comment: `join()` blocks the calling thread until the other thread finishes. So, while you have to `join()` a thread (don't use `detach()` without thinking it through carefully), putting it right after creating the thread means that the creating thread won't make any progress; you could just as well call the function in that thread instead of creating a new one.

Comment: Use `std::jthread` without required call to `join`.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

If you use `join()` right after starting the new thread then it will block (wait) execution on the `join()` call until the new thread is finished running (defeating the whole purpose of the parallelization you get from starting the new thread). Therefore, if you want to execute "some code" on the main thread while thread `t` is executing, `join()` should come after "some code".